# Does Nexus 3 support Maven?

Tags: maven, nexus

This looks like a simple question but I haven't been able to find the answer. I'm looking to try out Nexus and in the [download page](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype) I see:

```
Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.x
Manage these formats:
Docker NuGet npm Bower PyPI Ruby Gems

Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.x
Manage these formats:
Maven P2 OBR Yum
```

Does it mean that Nexus 3 doesn't support Maven?

Comment: It supports Maven See the docs: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my company we are using Nexus 3 as repository for jars with maven, and everything is fine with that.

Notice that in Nexus 3 you can't upload a third party jars from the UI like Nexus 2. It's the only disadvantage that I found.

Answer (score 2):

Nexus Repository 3 does in fact support Maven (2) as a format. The wording here was more so historically such that people wandering in might be better served using Nexus Repository 2 for Maven, since it has quite a lot of features that were built specifically with Maven in mind. However the gap has been closed fairly significantly, and at this point I think you'd be well served to use Nexus Repository 3. I'll see if I can get the download page updated to reflect that.